# Залогиниться в гугле из консоли c#

Tags: c#, консоль

Доброго времени суток всем!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в **консольном** приложении можно ввести набор символов в окна логин-пароль на сайте gmail com?
Или, скажем, программно нажать клавиши клавиатуры в заданном порядке?
Быть может, есть вариант копировать заранее указанные символы из консоли в форму гугл?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо здесь не поможет ! ибо вы понятия не имеете что вам нужно, для работы с серверами, и сайтами вам нужно изучить взаимодействие клиент-сервер - протоколы этих взаимодействий, запросы к серверу на интересующем вас языке в данном случаи C#, никто за вас писать код не будет. пожалуйста!

Comment: Ставите Fiddler или Wireshark, логинитесь на gmail как обычно, смотрите, какие запросы были отправлены. Затем такие же запросы отправляете из кода C#. Сделать это можно с помощью классов `HttpClient`, `WebClient`, `HttpWebRequest`. Тип приложения при этом совершенно не важен.

Comment: Или используете postman-intercepror, а потом пойманные в постмане запросы смотрите в виде кода на C# и копипастите в свой проект.

Comment: ну или смотрите в сторону [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы хотите сделать, легко решается с помощью **Selenium**. Это мощное средство для автоматизации работы с браузером.

Установите пакет **Selenium.WebDriver**, и:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
...

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Url = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin";

    var inputEmail = driver.FindElementById("identifierId");//это Id инпута для ввода email
    inputEmail.SendKeys("user@gmail.com");

    var btnNext = driver.FindElementById("identifierNext");//это Id кнопки "Далее"
    btnNext.Click();

    ...

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Естественно, чтобы вводить текст в инпуты и нажимать на кнопки, нужно предварительно ручками найти их на странице (изучив код страницы) и понять, как их можно программно идентифицировать. В приведенном примере используются Id элементов.